# How to get text from AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my app which works. I have successfully created an `onClickItemListener`. The question is how to grab the text the user selected.

And this is the thing: I have an `ArrayList` with words being passed to the `Adapter` to search for suggestions. As the user types a word the suggestions list gets shorter (in rows on the UI side) so when i want to get the word from the `ArrayList` at the index the user selected i get the wrong word because the indexes doesn't match.

How can I get the text (`String`) the user chose without having to mess with the index?

Here's my code:

```
public class AutocompleteActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private DBManager m_db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete);

        m_db = new DBManager(this);
        final ArrayList<String> words = m_db.selectAllWords();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, words);

        AutoCompleteTextView tv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        tv.setThreshold(1);
        tv.setAdapter(adapter);

        tv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.i("SELECTED TEXT WAS------->", words.get(arg2));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this code snippet, it helped for that which took me almost 6 hrs to do. +1 for that

Comment: Code worked. A small tip for beginners like me, After pasting this code, click on the field and type a letter to see the suggestion box coming down. I did pasted the code, clicked on the filed and waited for the suggestion box to POPUP which will never open up. But there is showDialogBox() method to display the POPUP.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`arg0` being your `AdapterView` and `arg2` the position.

Have you tried:

```
arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Comment: i looking for text which is selected by user not a id

Comment: arg3 is id from database. we can use it directly

Answer (score 63):

Yeah... unfortunately the name of the parameters on the onItemClick method you must implement are not so self-descriptive but here is an example with the names of what they are:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        String selection = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //TODO Do something with the selected text
    }
});
```

- parent The AdapterView where the click happened.
- view The view within
  the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the
  adapter)
- position The position of the view in the adapter
- id   The row id of the item that was clicked.

For more info see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Comment: Your suggestion is working fine instead of the selected answers.

Answer (score 10):

I think what you are looking for is this.

```
String s = this.mCountry.getEditableText().toString();
```

Where `mCountry` is the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
this.mCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries);
    this.mCountry.setAdapter(adapterCountry);
```

`mCountry` is the list of countries, and I wanted to save the country selected in `SharedPreferences`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

***Easiest of all***

For Getting text of the selected suggestion in AutoCompleteTextView use this

```
      autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("========>>", autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
txtPurpose.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            Purpose selected = (Purpose) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
            txtPurpose.setTag(selected);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

One another of getting text of suggestion selected in `AutoCompleteTextView` is

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
{
    TextView txtvw=(TextView) view;
    String str=txtvw.getText().toString();
    int index = contactNames.indexOf(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that will solve the problem.

```
 private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        int index = (int) view.getTag();
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(index);
        if (item instanceof SearchItemShareConnectionDAO) {
            SearchItemShareConnectionDAO dao = (SearchItemShareConnectionDAO) item;

        }
    }
};
```

SetTag(Dao.getPosition) in getView() method of adapter.

Comment: you r right. this will give us particular data. from Tag of view :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the text of the displayed item selected by the user

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String selectedItemText = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    Log.i("myTag", "SELECTED TEXT WAS["+selectedItemText+"]);
}
```

Following best practices, please use some form of descriptive nomenclature for your variables, your code will make more sense:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterViewIn, View viewIn, int selectedItemIndexIn, long id)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a way to get item outside the `onItemClick`:

```
int index = tv.getListSelection();
if (index != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
    Object item = tv.getAdapter().getItem(index);
}
```

beware that `int getListSelection()` may return `ListView.INVALID_POSITION` if there is no dropdown or if there is no selection.

Comment: Strange, but `index  == -1` (API 29 emulator ).

Comment: @CoolMind this is possible and is expected behavior `ListView.INVALID_POSITION = -1`

Answer (score 0):

For me, but on `setOnItemSelectedListener()`:

```
arg0.getSelectedItem();
```

was enough. The same should work on `setOnItemClickListener()` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version

```
autoCompleteId.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            Log.d("SELECTED ITEM", selectedItem )
        }
```

Output:

```
D/CLASSROOM: selectedItem
```