# How to extract String using AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I know that there are multiple posts in Stackoverflow addressing this query. However, for some reason I am still failing to extract the string from `AutoCompleteTextView`. I tried using the `onItemClickListener` for this purpose. I am unable to identify where I am going wrong.

**The Code :**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    addPurchaseItemName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.addPurchaseProductName);

    vivzHelper = new VivzDatabaseAdapter(this);

    String[] autoCompleteName = vivzHelper.getInventoryNameFilterBySupplierName(vivzHelper.getSupplierID(param1));
    ArrayAdapter<String> NameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, autoCompleteName);
    addPurchaseItemName.setThreshold(1);// starts working from first char
    addPurchaseItemName.setAdapter(NameAdapter);

    addPurchaseItemName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            itemName = String.valueOf(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
        }
    });

}
```

I want to assign the value of the extracted string to `itemName` which is initialized at the beginning of the activity. Can some one point out where am I going wrong? I have surfed multiple resources. Maybe, I am missing something.

**Note :**

This code was already posted to address a an issue on [IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762009/why-am-i-getting-an-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-bind-value-at-index?noredirect=1#comment47706929_29762009) in StackOverFlow a couple of days ago. Since, the topic of that question doesn't point more specifically the problem posted here, I thought that posting a new question will make sense. Hence I hope, my question *won't be down-voted* or edited as *duplicate*

**Update 01 : @Deividi Cavarzan forgot including the below line of code when editing this question**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> NameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, autoCompleteName);
```

**Update 02 : Declaring the itemName**

```
public class AddPurchase extends ActionBarActivity {

AutoCompleteTextView addPurchaseItemName;
String itemName;
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of things that are unnecessary for the question and made it confuse to understand. Try to put only parts that are relevant, and also the declaration of the `itemName` variable

Comment: Can you show how you initialize `itemName`?  Also, add a log entry to `onItemClick()` and log the value of `itemName`.

Comment: post the code related to `NameAdapter`

Comment: I have updated above on how I declared the `itemName` variable

Answer (score 0):

try to get the `itemName` on `addTextChangedListener` callback

```
addPurchaseItemName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        itemName = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {                

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: tried using `addTextChangedListener()`. Shows the same exception

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get the selected item string from auto complete, then

```
itemName = addPurchaseItemName.getText();
```

or even better-

```
itemName = addPurchaseItemName.getText().toString().trim();
```

### Updated answer

instead of setting `onItemClickListener` , set  `OnItemSelectedListener` , this should definitely work.

```
addPurchaseItemName.setOnSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //... your stuff
        itemName = addPurchaseItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected value - "+itemName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already tried using `itemName = addPurchaseItemName.getText().toString()`. But, still shows an exception

Comment: what is the exception? can you post the logcat? the code snippet I answered works perfectly unless we have other problems.

Comment: I am sorry. The second sentence isn't an response to you. Actually, there arises no exception in your case. However, the string value of `itemName` remains null which I have confirmed using a Toast. Sorry again.

Comment: Where are you putting the Toast?, do your onItemClick() get called at all?