# How to get the index of the Text selected in an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

```
AutoCompleteTextView mActv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewbyId(R.id.m_actv);
ArrayAdapter<String> AutoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.dropdown_text, Names);
mActv.setAdapter(AutoCompleteAdapter);
```

**Names** is a String array.

Is it possible to get the **index** of the text selected from the dropdown??

Thank You.

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Comment: try taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819813/how-to-get-text-from-autocomplete-textview-android

Comment: Solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819813/how-to-get-text-from-autocomplete-textview-android/37343444#37343444

Comment: I think the solution for your problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621762/how-to-find-the-position-of-item-in-a-autocompletetextview-filled-with-array).. check it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add `OnItemClickListener` (for clicked item) or `OnItemSelectedListener`(for items selcted using a Trackball, Up/Down keys) to the `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
mActv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
                long id) {
              String item = arg1.getItemAtPosition(pos);
               //your stuff
           }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah. This is the first thing i tried. But here it gives the **position** of the text selected from the **dropdown**, not the index of the String from the Array i used to populate :(

Comment: Isn't the order remain same? I mean in the Array and the list which comes in the dropdown?

Comment: But depending on the initial few **Characters** i type in, the dropdown changes (Expected behavior of an AutoCompleteTextView).

Comment: I faced the same problem you have, what I did is a custom adapter where you can set objects instead of strings so you can access to the selected object variables.

Comment: `String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);` This is the correct answer, Its not `arg1.getItemAtPosition`

Answer (score 3):

Implement onItemClickListener for AutoCompleteTextView, then use indexOf on your list to find the index of selected item.

```
actvCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
          long arg3) {
          int index = cityNames.indexOf(actvCity.getText().toString());
          // Do Whatever you want to do ;)
     }
});
```

Comment: There is no indexOf method on AutoCompleteTextView!

Answer (score 2):

Try [`AutoCompleteTextView#getListSelection()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#getListSelection%28%29).

Comment: This always returns **-1**. Which is the **ListView.INVALID_POSITION** as given in the link provided by you.

Comment: This works while the dropdown list is open, however you are asking a tricky question since the list (and therefor the index) changes depending on the AutoCompleteTextView's input... If `Names` is a `List<String>` then you can use `indexOf()` to find the position of the a string after it has been selected.

Comment: I'm also finding that `getListSelection()` is always returning `-1` even when the `AutoCompleteTextView` is visible and something is selected.  Am I going crazy?

Answer (score 1):

```
Item.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //// id contains item if from database
                    ItemNoSelected = id;
                }
            });
```

id is from database we can use it