# how to find the position of item in a AutoCompletetextview filled with Array

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an array (*array1*  with `States`) and `AutoCompleteTextview` in which I'm filling it with *array1*. When I select the value from `AutocompleteTextView` I select a `state` from AutoCompleteTextView Dropdown

What I want is to get the **position** of the item from *array1* which I've selected.
What I've tried is `OnClickEvent` of `AutocompelteTextView`.

```
STATE.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String num = selection;
    }
});
```

It ss giving me the value which I selected from dropdown but i want to get the `position of the value` in *array1*. For Example I have an array of size 4, like array1 = {A,B,C,D}, and if I select B it should return me B position in Array i.e 2.

I hope I made it clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use int position variable for the position of the value in onItemClick Listener.

Comment: Item.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //// id contains item if from database
                    ItemNoSelected = id;
                }
            });  --- here id is id from database

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the **position** variable in the `onItemClick`.

```
STATE.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        int pos = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < yourarray.length; i++) {
            if (yourarray[i].equals(selection)) {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Position " + pos); //check it now in Logcat
    }
});
```

Comment: this does not give me correct position 
i want the position of Variable from Array but it gives the position from the AutocompleteDropdown i see

Comment: But what if it is not Array instead it is ArrayList<String>

Comment: Problem is is there are two identical names in the autocomplete.

Comment: remember never compare string

Answer (score 3):

Use List instead of Array. Implement onItemClickListener for AutoCompleteTextView, then use indexOf on your list to find the index of selected item.

```
actvCity.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
          long arg3) {
          int index = cityNames.indexOf(actvCity.getText().toString());
          // Do Whatever you want to do ;)
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
            {
                TextView txtvw=(TextView) view;
                String str=txtvw.getText().toString();
                int index = contactNames.indexOf(str);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Item.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //// id contains item if from database
                    ItemNoSelected = id;
                }
            });
```

id is from database, we can use that

Answer (score -3):

You can find the parent string in the clickItem listener.
OSchools in this case is the custom ArrayList.

```
Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
for(OSchools d : data){
Log.e("name",d.getName());
String name = d.getName();
if(d.getName() != null && name.contains(item.toString())){
       ID = d.getID();
}
```

Comment: An answer based only on code it's not considered a proper SO answer. Could you add explanation for your code? (from review)